# What is the name of this type of function in PHP

Tags: php, php-7

I usually see this type of functions in classes when I explore a few laravel packages code, i want to know what is the name of this type of functions and how to use it, for example:

```
protected function getFiles(): Filesystem
{

}
```

or

```
protected function getConfigPath(): string
{

}
```

A PHP Documentation link would be useful.

Comment: [Return type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration) added PHP 7.

Comment: @Dharman, done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Return type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration)** were added in PHP 7.

Similar to argument type declarations, return type declarations
define the **type** of the value that will be returned by a function. The available types are the same as those available for [argument type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).

```
<?php
function sum($a, $b): float {
    return $a + $b;
}
```

> As of PHP 7.1.0, return values can be marked as nullable by prefixing
>   the type name with a question mark (?).

```
?string ?int ?array ?bool ?float
```

This allows the function to return the type defined or null, anything else will throw a [TypeError](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php) if using **Strict Mode**, the default.

The [`strict_types`](https://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict) directive can be set globally, or toggled in code using the [`declare`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php) construct.

```
declare(strict_types=1);
```

One of the primary benefits of using these features in PHP is clearer code. There is no ambiguity about the functions input and output. It also help detect silly mistakes like comparing a string and integer type value - or rather perform those evaluations in a more predictable way.

Here are some other discussions on this topic:

- [Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)
- [Type casting variables in PHP, what is the practical reason for doing this?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/24378/type-casting-variables-in-php-what-is-the-practical-reason-for-doing-this)
- [What does strict types do in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723637/what-does-strict-types-do-in-php)
- [Are scalar and strict types in PHP7 a performance enhancing feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940170/are-scalar-and-strict-types-in-php7-a-performance-enhancing-feature)